# Avoid repeating myself

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there is a way to write a shorter version of the following js code. In the end I'm just repeating myself over and over again. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

```
if (designVal == 0 && colorVal == 0) {
    design01yellow.style.display = "block";
    design01black.style.display = "none";
    design01blue.style.display = "none";
    design01grey.style.display = "none";
    design02yellow.style.display = "none";
    design02black.style.display = "none";
    design02blue.style.display = "none";
    design02grey.style.display = "none";
    design03yellow.style.display = "none";
    design03black.style.display = "none";
    design03blue.style.display = "none";
    design03grey.style.display = "none";
} else if (designVal == 0 && colorVal == 1) {
    design01yellow.style.display = "none";
    design01black.style.display = "block";
    design01blue.style.display = "none";
    design01grey.style.display = "none";
    design02yellow.style.display = "none";
    design02black.style.display = "none";
    design02blue.style.display = "none";
    design02grey.style.display = "none";
    design03yellow.style.display = "none";
    design03black.style.display = "none";
    design03blue.style.display = "none";
    design03grey.style.display = "none";
} else if (designVal == 0 && colorVal == 2) {
    design01yellow.style.display = "none";
    design01black.style.display = "none";
    design01blue.style.display = "block";
    design01grey.style.display = "none";
    design02yellow.style.display = "none";
    design02black.style.display = "none";
    design02blue.style.display = "none";
    design02grey.style.display = "none";
    design03yellow.style.display = "none";
    design03black.style.display = "none";
    design03blue.style.display = "none";
    design03grey.style.display = "none";
} else if 
///AND SO ON
```

Comment: make json file based data

Comment: I would put a class like "yellow" "blue" on some parent element, and then CSS all the rest.

Comment: You could just normalize all to 'none' and then only change the one you want to set to 'block'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the elements a common class (e.g. `class="design"`). Loop over them, setting them all to `none`, then set the specific element to `block`.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".design").forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
if (designVal == 0 && colorVal == 0) {
    design01yellow.style.display = "block";
} else if (designVal == 0 && colorVal == 1) {
    design01black.style.display = "block";
} ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd normalize them to 'display: none' and then only set the one you want to `display: block`.

```js
if (designVal === 0) {
  design01yellow.style.display = "none";
  design01black.style.display = "none";
  design01blue.style.display = "none";
  design01grey.style.display = "none";
  design02yellow.style.display = "none";
  design02black.style.display = "none";
  design02blue.style.display = "none";
  design02grey.style.display = "none";
  design03yellow.style.display = "none";
  design03black.style.display = "none";
  design03blue.style.display = "none";
  design03grey.style.display = "none";

  if(colorVal === 0) {
    design01yellow.style.display = "block";
  } else if (colorVal === 1) {
    design01black.style.display = "block";
  } else if (colorVal === 2) {
    design01blue.style.display = "block";
  }

  // and so on
}
```